# How to determine if the text has changed or no in the TextField with JavaFX?

Tags: text, javafx, textfield

i have TextField contains a text like: "hello!" and this text if it changed to another text should do something the main problem is how to check if this TextField contains new value (new text) instead of the first text wrote should do something. can any body show me how to do that and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ChangeListener to the [textProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textProperty--) of the [TextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html) like this:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
            TextField textField = new TextField();

            textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                    System.out.println(observable + ", " + oldValue + ", " + newValue);
                }
            });

            root.getChildren().add( textField);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```